Is the gravitational potential energy of an object on the ground 0?
In class, we were reviewing kinetic and potential energy and my teacher claimed that on the ground, objects have potential energy. However, as they cannot fall further, isn't their gravitational potential energy 0? If this is the case, however, do they still have potential, or stored energy, on the ground?

Put a ball on your hand. The ball cannot fall further. Take your hand away and the ball falls. So clearly, there was still potential energy, with respect to the Earth. Remove the Earth and you'll probably be concerned about the potential energy related to the sun. As all the other answers mention, it depends on your frame of reference

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/155690/2451 and links therein.

Gravitational potential energy only makes sense relative to two points and you can set any one point to any potential you want since only differences in potential energy matter. So you can call potential 0 at the surface of earth, positive above it, and negative if it were to fall in a nearby hole, indicating additional energy would be needed to lift it back up to the region of zero potential.
It's customary to associate a negative potential with a particle in a bounded system implying energy must be added to remove it from the system. Specifics of the problem help determine a use place to associated 0 potential.

Once you understand that, you understand the concept of electrical voltage (and why birds do not get an electric shock when sitting on a high-voltage power line) ...

We can use any reference point setting our energy levels.   We can set the zero point at the level of a table, the floor of a laboratory, zero mean sea level, or any other point.
We can do this because there is no problem with assigning a negative potential energy.   As long as we use the same reference point throughout the problem, any differences will cancel the reference and only the changes in potential energy will appear.
Saying an object has zero potential energy is only useful after a frame of reference has been chosen.

Welcome to gauge invariance. You can define a potential, $\Phi(z)$, but all physics is invariant under the global transformation:
$$ \Phi(z) \rightarrow \Phi(z) + C $$
where $C$ is a constant.

Obviously correct answer but probably way too advanced for a highschool level student.

@infinitezero ya never know, tho. There won't be a quiz on my answers, so OP can take it or leave it.

Unless the objects are in the center of (local) gravity, they do have potential energy. Say you have lump of lead, and you dig a tunnel beneath it, than it still could fall downwards.

So essentially, the point at which GPE equals 0 can be defined depending on what you want to set it to?
